# Sort WP_Query with numeric custom field

Tags: custom-field, sort

I have added a numeric field (called 'video_order') to a certain post type, via ACF.

I would like to sort the list of posts, by that numeric field.
I have made sure to go through the posts and give them all a value.

This is the Query i have tried, which does not seem to work (there is just no sorting based on that numeric field)

Can someone suggest something?

Thanks!

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'post_sermons',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => ot_get_option('wpl_sermon_per_page'),
   'paged'=> $paged,
   'orderby' => 'video_order',
   'order' => 'ASC' 
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your meta key should be specified as the `meta_key` argument, and `orderby` should be `meta_value_num`:

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'post_sermons',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => ot_get_option('wpl_sermon_per_page'),
   'paged'=> $paged,
   'meta_key' => 'video_order',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC' 
);
```

See [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for explanations of query arguments.